# Huge swap usage due to multiple Java instances

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, java

I have 16 inch MacBook Pro M1 Pro with 16 GB of RAM and use it for Android Development

I am suffering from high memory/swap usage that causes the device to be slow due to multiple Java instances that fire once I hit build on Android Studio, please check the attached screenshots.

As you see in this case I have two Java instances one takes 3.55GB and the other 2.95 from RAM and this is not the worst time, sometimes I find 4 instances!! and I always have memory pressure, this is not why I bought this machine, it is supposed to be powerful and handle the memory more efficiently!

I need a way to minimize the Java instances to just one instance

Is there any way to solve the multiple Java processes issue?

[image: Memory usage with two instances]

Memory/CPU usage with three instances:

[image: Memory usage with three instances]

[image: CPU usage]

Comment: What is the CPU usage like? I've seen M-series Macs cope with considerably more data than that, without any performance penalty.

Comment: @benwiggy Updated the question with screenshots.

Comment: This sounds like your Java app has a memory leak or at the very minimum, poor memory management.  Is this Java app something you developed?  If so, it might be a better fit on [SO]

Comment: I think you should ask the developers of Android Studio.

Comment: @Allan Java is related to the JDK

Comment: @benwiggy I believe they receive a lot of this since the beginning of Android Studio development

Comment: I understand that @Mohamed. What does that have to do with a possible memory leak of the Java app?

Comment: @Allan I think those instances are related to the Gradle system and the emulator,  I was hoping someone tell me a way to make both use the same java instance

Comment: Ahh… not at all familiar with that particular tool, but I have seen where things like this are “cobbled” together to rush it to market (for devs) to get them working asap. Quality and efficiency go out the window